# application wise battery usage on android device through adb shell dumpsys

Tags: android

how do I get application wise battery usage on android device

I have used below command and the out put listed below.

```
adb shell dumpsys batterystats --unplugged com.honeywell.tools.ezconfig
```

How do I convert below information into useful?. Like 15% battery consumed by ezconfig app.

```
Battery History:
          -9m49s747ms 100 64020043 status=discharging health=good plug=none temp
=317 volt=4145 +wifi +wifi_running +wake_lock +sensor brightness=light signal_st
rength=great
          -9m49s507ms 100 24020043 -wake_lock
          -9m46s968ms 100 24020043
          -9m43s749ms 100 24020043 volt=4107
          -9m38s472ms 100 240a0043 status=full plug=ac temp=318 +plugged

Per-PID Stats:
  PID 1184 wake time: +1s315ms
  PID 5096 wake time: +1s18ms
  PID 1184 wake time: +29ms
  PID 1945 wake time: +188ms
  PID 2125 wake time: +42ms
  PID 3757 wake time: +25ms
  PID 1184 wake time: +11ms
  PID 1184 wake time: +12ms
  PID 4008 wake time: +90ms
  PID 7441 wake time: +28ms

Statistics since last unplugged:
  Time on battery: 11s 275ms (1.9%) realtime, 11s 275ms (1.9%) uptime
  Total run time: 9m 49s 748ms realtime, 9m 49s 748ms uptime,
  Screen on: 0ms (0.0%), Input events: 0, Active phone call: 0ms (0.0%)
  Screen brightnesses: No activity
  Mobile total received: 0B, Total sent: 0B
  Wi-Fi total received: 0B, Total sent: 0B
  Total full wakelock time: 0ms , Total partial wakelock time: 1s 151ms
  Signal levels: great 11s 275ms (100.0%) 0x
  Signal scanning time: 0ms
  Radio types: none 11s 275ms (100.0%) 0x
  Radio data uptime when unplugged: 0 ms
  Wifi on: 11s 275ms (100.0%), Wifi running: 11s 275ms (100.0%), Bluetooth on: 0
ms (0.0%)

  Device is currently plugged into power
    Last discharge cycle start level: 100
    Last discharge cycle end level: 100
    Amount discharged while screen on: 0
    Amount discharged while screen off: 0

  1000:
    User activity: 6 other, 1 touch
    Wake lock SCREEN_FROZEN: 187ms partial (1 times) realtime
    Wake lock StartingDockService: 832ms partial (1 times) realtime
    Wake lock DockObserver: 10ms partial (1 times) realtime
    Wake lock AlarmManager: 56ms partial (1 times) realtime
    TOTAL wake: 1s 85ms partial realtime
    Sensor 21: 11s 275ms realtime (0 times)
    Sensor 33: 11s 275ms realtime (0 times)
    Proc mm-pp-daemon:
      CPU: 0ms usr + 180ms krn ; 0ms fg
    Proc charger_monitor:
      CPU: 0ms usr + 20ms krn ; 0ms fg
    Proc com.honeywell.licenseservice:
      CPU: 0ms usr + 10ms krn ; 0ms fg
    Proc com.qualcomm.qualcommsettings:
      CPU: 0ms usr + 10ms krn ; 0ms fg
    Proc surfaceflinger:
      CPU: 70ms usr + 100ms krn ; 0ms fg
    Proc com.android.settings:
      CPU: 10ms usr + 0ms krn ; 0ms fg
    Proc system_server:
      CPU: 540ms usr + 370ms krn ; 0ms fg
    Proc com.hsm.android.counters:
      CPU: 20ms usr + 0ms krn ; 0ms fg
    Proc com.honeywell.tools.honsystemservice:
      CPU: 10ms usr + 0ms krn ; 0ms fg
    Apk com.android.settings:
      Service com.android.settings.bluetooth.DockService:
        Created for: 1s 8ms uptime
        Starts: 1, launches: 1
```